# How to find all possible values for a particular result in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have 3 values in cells A1, A2 and A3. Every value has limited value range. For example A2 value can only be number from 1 to 100.  These 3 values are used in calculation and stored in a result cell.

I wonder how to find all possible values of A1, A2 and A3 for a particular result. For example if the formula for the calculation is `A1*0.1+A2*100/A3/4` and the result is 48, then one of possible value collections would be 30,90,50. I want to find all of them.

Is this possible to do with excel? If yes, then how?

Comment: I assume you only want integers. first you need to change the formula so A3 is alone at one side of the equation. Then create a 2D array for all possible numbers for A1 and A2. with your equation, you'll get all correct answers for A3 as an 2D array. This can be output via the LARGE function. you just need to eliminate unwanted outputs for A3

Comment: however, if you want ALL possibilities, then have in mind that your equation has an infinite amount of answers ;P

Comment: @DirkReichel it hasn't an infinite amount of answers because A1, A2 and A3 have bounds.

Comment: only if you are looking for integers. with decimals there is no limit. basic math proves that... Set A1 to 10 then `100*A2 / 4*A3` equals 47 which is `A2 / 1.88 = A3` now each possible value between 1.88 and 100 for A2 will be a valid value to have A3 in the range of 1 and 53.19... this way unlimited answers just for A1 is 10 ;)